# Is there any good open-source or freely available Chinese segmentation algorithm available?

Tags: algorithm, open-source, cjk, text-segmentation

As phrased in the question, I'm looking for a free and/or open-source text-segmentation algorithm for Chinese, I do understand it is a very difficult task to solve, as there are many ambiguities involed. I know there's google's API, but well it is rather a black-box, i.e. not many information of what it is doing are passing through.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The keyword `text-segmentation for Chinese` should be `中文分词` in Chinese.

**Good and active open-source text-segmentation algorithm** :

1. **[盘古分词(Pan Gu Segment)](http://pangusegment.codeplex.com/)** : `C#`, [**`Snapshot`**](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=pangusegment&DownloadId=79153)
2. **[ik-analyzer](http://code.google.com/p/ik-analyzer/)** : `Java`
3. **[ICTCLAS](http://ictclas.org/index.html)** : `C/C++, Java, C#`, [**`Demo`**](http://ictclas.org/ictclas_demo.html)
4. **[NlpBamboo](http://www.oschina.net/p/nlpbamboo)** : `C, PHP, PostgreSQL`
5. **[HTTPCWS](http://code.google.com/p/httpcws/)** : based on `ICTCLAS`, [**`Demo`**](http://blog.s135.com/demo/httpcws/)
6. **[mmseg4j](http://code.google.com/p/mmseg4j/)** : `Java`
7. **[fudannlp](http://code.google.com/p/fudannlp/)** : `Java`, [**`Demo`**](http://jkx.fudan.edu.cn/nlp/)
8. **[smallseg](http://code.google.com/p/smallseg/)** : `Python, Java`, [**`Demo`**](http://smallseg.appspot.com/smallseg)
9. **[nseg](https://github.com/mountain/nseg)** : NodeJS
10. **[mini-segmenter](https://code.google.com/p/mini-segmenter/)**: `python`

**Other**

1. **Google Code** : [http://code.google.com/query/#q=中文分词](http://code.google.com/query/#q=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D)
2. **[OSChina (Open Source China)](http://www.oschina.net/project/tag/264/segment?sort=view&lang=0&os=0)**

**Sample**

1. **[Google Chrome (Chromium)](http://www.chromium.org/)** : [`src`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc), [`cc_cedict.txt (73,145 Chinese words/pharases)`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/icu38/source/data/brkitr/cc_cedict.txt)

   - In `text field` or `textarea` of **Google Chrome** with Chinese sentences, press
     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
   - `Double click` on `中文分词指的是将一个汉字序列切分成一个一个单独的词`

Comment: Good list. How about [smallseg](http://code.google.com/p/smallseg/), does it qualify as good and active?

Comment: Best `Chinese text-segmentation` library for Python?

Comment: http://ictclas.org/index.html looks fantastic, even with part of speech

Comment: what does chrome use for segmenting text?

Answer (score 8):

Stanford segment using CRF algorithmn.

It's under GPL

link page is :  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml

Answer (score 1):

[ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) has details on universal text segmentation - http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis

Answer (score 0):

Cursory Googling for "text segmentation chinese open source" reveals this library, which may or may not be what you're looking for...:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktdictseg/

The results hint at a few alternative venues to look for an open-source library, too:

- Searching for an open-source search implementation that might work with Chinese.
- Searching for an open-source plagiarism detection implementation that might with Chinese.