# How to tokenize Chinese language document

Tags: java, tokenize

I will be getting document written in Chinese language for which I have to tokenize and keep it in database table. I was trying the CJKBigramFilter of Lucene but all it does is unite the 2 character together for which the meaning is different then what is there in document. Suppose this is a line in the file "Hello My name is Pradeep" which in chinese tradition is "你好我的名字是普拉迪普". When I tokenize it, it gets converted to the 2 letter words below.
你好 - Hello
名字 - Name
好我 - Well I
字是 - Word is
我的 - My
拉迪 - Radi
是普 - Is the S & P
普拉 - Pula
的名 - In the name of
迪普 - Dipp.
All I want is it to convert to same English translation.
I am using Lucene for this...if you have any other favourable opne source please direct me to that.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626912/how-does-tokenization-and-pattern-matching-work-in-chinese

Comment: Well it is totally different in the sense that Stanford have their own setup for tokenizing chinese character which I cannot use as I am using Lucene. I jsut wanted to know that in Lucene how can i tokenize Chinese character as such describe above in my problem statment.

Answer (score 4):

Though may be too late, you might try U-Tokenizer which is an online API, it is available for free.
See http://tokenizer.tool.uniwits.com/

Comment: Can you please add a bit more to your answer and explain how one could use the site.

Comment: Please read http://tokenizer.tool.uniwits.com/qx-cmd-api.html for a guide.  If you have detailed questions, I will try to answer specifically.

Comment: it's dead, gone

Comment: Aaand, this is exactly why link-only answers are bad practice. The TLD is just a "build your own homepage" landing page. It would have been nice to know more about the "tokenizer.tool" in case it's worth chasing after it elsewhere...

Answer (score 3):

If you want a full blown NLP parser, checkout out http://nlp.stanford.edu

If you want a simple, one-off solution for Chinese, here is what I used.

First load a Chinese dictionary into a Trie (Prefix-Tree) to reduce memory footprint. I then walked through the sentences a character at a time observing wither substrings existed in the dictionary. If they did, I would parse it as a token. The algorithm could likely be improved greatly, but this has served me well. :)

```
public class ChineseWordTokenizer implements WordTokenizer {

    private static final int MAX_MISSES = 6;

    // example implementation: http://www.kennycason.com/posts/2012-03-20-java-trie-prefix-tree.html
    private StringTrie library;

    private boolean loadTraditional;

    public ChineseWordTokenizer() {
        this(true);
    }

    public ChineseWordTokenizer(boolean loadTraditional) {
        loadLibrary();
        this.loadTraditional = loadTraditional;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] parse(String sentence) {
        final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String word;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            int len = 1;
            boolean loop = false;
            int misses = 0;
            int lastCorrectLen = 1;
            boolean somethingFound = false;
            do {
                word = sentence.substring(i, i + len);
                if (library.contains(word)) {
                    somethingFound = true;
                    lastCorrectLen = len;
                    loop = true;
                } else {
                    misses++;
                    loop = misses < MAX_MISSES;
                }
                len++;
                if(i + len > sentence.length()) {;
                    loop = false;
                }        
            } while (loop);

            if(somethingFound) {
                word = sentence.substring(i, i + lastCorrectLen);
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(word)) {
                    words.add(word);
                    i += lastCorrectLen - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
    }

    private void loadLibrary() {
        library = new StringTrie();
        library.loadFile("classify/nlp/dict/chinese_simple.list");
        if(loadTraditional) {
            library.loadFile("classify/nlp/dict/chinese_traditional.list");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a Unit Test

```
public class TestChineseWordTokenizer {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        WordTokenizer tokenizer = new ChineseWordTokenizer();
        System.out.println("load time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms");

        String[] words = tokenizer.tokenize("弹道导弹");
        print(words);
        assertEquals(1, words.length);

        words = tokenizer.tokenize("美国人的文化.dog");
        print(words);
        assertEquals(3, words.length);

        words = tokenizer.tokenize("我是美国人");
        print(words);
        assertEquals(3, words.length);

        words = tokenizer.tokenize("政府依照法律行使执法权，如果超出法律赋予的权限范围，就是“滥用职权”；如果没有完全行使执法权，就是“不作为”。两者都是政府的错误。");
        print(words);

        words = tokenizer.tokenize("国家都有自己的政府。政府是税收的主体，可以实现福利的合理利用。");
        print(words);
    }

    private void print(String[] words) {
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for(String word : words) {
            System.out.print(word + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

And Here are the results

```
Load Complete: 102135 Entries
load time: 236 ms
[ 弹道导弹 ]
[ 美国人 的 文化 ]
[ 我 是 美国人 ]
[ 政府 依照 法律 行使 执法 权 如果 超出 法律 赋予 的 权限 范围 就是 滥用职权 如果 没有 完全 行使 执法 权 就是 不 作为 两者 都 是 政府 的 错误 ]
[ 国家 都 有 自己 的 政府 政府 是 税收 的 主体 可以 实现 福利 的 合理 利用 ]
```

Comment: Hi Kenny! I'd like to give your solution a try and compare its performance with my current tokenizer. Could you point me to where to search for a usable dictionary? I failed to find it in your github repository as well as in stanford nlp data... Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this resource, its a chinese tokenizer using CC-CEDICT

https://github.com/yishn/chinese-tokenizer